# Retornar datas entre quantidade de dias

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Gostaria de saber como que eu faço:

Quero uma variável do tipo dias

depois pegar o resultado desta variável e fazer um select entre as datas contando o numero de dias

Alguma solução ou exemplo?

Comment: Felipe: **(1)** Você quer ou você tem *uma variável do tipo dias*? **(2)** Acrescente  informações no corpo de sua pergunta: tabelas, colunas, dados de exemplo etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, mas se quer fazer uma procedure, tente dessa maneira.

```
declare @primeira_data datetime, @segunda_data datetime, @result int;
set @result:= Day(@primeira_data) - Day(@segunda_data);
```

Existe uma função que faz isso para você

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: só retire os : (dois pontos) o sql server não aceita isso.